# Javascript not working after deploying my next js build to a hosting cpanel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cpanel, vercel, turborepo

I have a project that i created using turbo-repo, next.js, typescript and tailwind css. Now i want to build and deploy my site to namecheap hosting by building my project using the command
`pnpm build` in the root directory
Also am using pnpm as the package manager

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "turbo run build",
    "dev": "turbo run dev --parallel",
    "lint": "turbo run lint",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx,md}\""
  },
```

And this was able to create a `.next` folder inside my next.js project in `apps/client/.next`
And inside the .next i have `cache, static, server` folder and some other json files

Now i then ran the command `pnpm export` to create the next.js output folder `apps/client/out/`

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "export": "next export"
  }
```

And this out folder contains my html css javascript that i can use to upload to my public_html in Cpanel. But the issue is that after uploading the files to my public_html the html and css shows and it's working but my javascript isn't working at all, like some buttons, actions aren't working properly

I even tried checking the out folder by using `http-server` and everything is working okay on it but not when i add it to the cpanel

So please does anyone know how i can fix this or is there a better way to go about doing this to make everything work properly

```
//my next.config.js
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["ui"]);

module.exports = withTM({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.pdf$/i,
      type: "asset/source",
    });

    return config;
  },
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
  // distDir: "build",
});
```

If you have any question or require some things please let me know

Comment: You probably want to deploy on vercel / netlify, your next app can't listen on the same port as whatever else is already listening

Comment: @pguardiario so those that mean that it isn't going to work on namecheap hosting?

Comment: I think there's a way to do it but nobody really does it that way. It's meant to be deployed on vercel / netlify